# Installing .NET application missing Microsoft.Cryptography.DKM in GAC

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gac

I have developed a Console app for Lync 2013 in VS 2012, targeting .NET 4.0. I have successfully installed the application on my own machine, but now I need to run it on another client, and I get this strange error. I have Googled the error, but have not found anything useful.

[image: Error message when installing Console application]

The error is in danish, but tells me that I am missing Microsoft.Cryptography.DKM version 1.11.0.0 in GAC.

I have not seen this error before, and it seems like it is not a common error, as it is hard to find any information about this on the internet.

Any advise any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: What kind of installer technology do you use?

Comment: Making a package (using publish, from build menu) from VS2012.

Comment: You are using Microsoft.Cryptography.DKM as part of your project, but I don't think that is part of a standard .NET install. Some extra software installed it. Where did you get Microsoft.Cryptography.DKM from?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The questions is why the VS2012 Publish doesn't pick that up as a dependency.

Comment: @Sylvester78 On the page where you start the publish wizard (Project > Properties > Publish), please look at the lists what "Application Files..." and the "Prerequisites..." buttons show.

Comment: @Sylvester78 Can it happen that you load that assembly programatically? (so there's no conventional explicit reference to it in the project)?

Comment: @Sylvester78 Also, does your app has to do anything with that DKM? Are you fiddling with any key management, cryptography in your app, or this DKM was a surprise for you?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by including all the assemblies from the UMCA 4.0 api, that was used in the project, which solved the issue. I was confused by this for me unknown assembly Microsoft.Cryptography.DKM.

Thank you Csaba Toth, for pointing me in the right direction. If you will write your comment as a reply to my question, I will mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I just had the same problem and this answer is not really clear:
Go to Project->xxxProperties
In the Publish tab click "Application files"
Change "Publish status" from "Prerequisite" to "Include"