# UCMA 4.0 application - missing SIPEPS.dll or one of dependencies

Tags: c#, ucma

I've just made a small LYNC application using UCMA 4.0 - it all runs nice on my local machine but I have problem installing it on destination server. I've already [fought and won with missing assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133471/installing-net-application-missing-microsoft-cryptography-dkm-in-gac/26598335#26598335) but still cannot run the program properly:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptionL Could not load file or assembly SIPEPS.dll or one of its dependencies.
```

OK - I've found some help suggesting changing the publication to x64 and .net framework to 4.5, which is fine since the server is 64 bit anyway... but that hasn't solved the problem: after running dependency checker I've found 
that I'm missing `IESHIMS.DLL, MSCOREE.DLL and OLE32.DLL`

wait, OLE32? For 64 bit?

Ok, it seems I can install it on other computers but not on the server... weird.

EDIT: problem seems to show with Windows Server 2008 R2, I can install it without issue on newer systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, it could be a number of things so I'll run through the list I always go through when doing this. If this doesn't help, provide a little more background and I might be able to give you a more useful answer.

Luckily UCMA 4.0 installs a whole lot easier than the previous versions did.  UCMA 4.0 applications *must* (*must*, *must*) be compiled 64-bit to run in production. The SDK will allow 32-bit compiles, but the SDK requires an installation of Visual Studio to install.  Because of the problems your running into, I'm led to believe you might be installing the wrong "kind" of UCMA bits on the server.

#### Check that you're using UCMA 4.0 Runtime, not SDK

On the server, you want to install the [UCMA 4.0 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34992), not the SDK.  That should get you your dependencies.  In the references within your application, you want only the Microsoft.Rtc components that you're using.  `SIPEPS.DLL` and such are used by them but in the projects I've written against UCMA, it is not referenced directly in any one of them.

#### Check your pre-reqs

I have UCMA 4.0 up and running (perfectly, first time) on Windows Server 2008 R2. I noticed on the pre-req's it had a requirement for Service Pack 1 to be installed (my environment is up to the latest patch levels on everything).

You didn't specify your patch levels and since you indicate that you're not having problems on later versions, I suspect this might have something to do with it.

You'll also need:

- .Net Framework 4.5 (latest 4.5 -- I think 4.5.2 as of this moment). Make sure this is installed before even running the installer for UCMA.
- Server has to be 64-bit (all of Lync has this requirement)
- If you are able to get up and running but have difficulty doing basic things related to connecting, etc, *check your AV software*.  I've encountered a situation where a Symantec Endpoint Protection interfered with UCMA despite having firewall rules in place that didn't *appear* to be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem with an application using UCMA 5.0, and installing the proper runtime solved it.